# Automapper EF Core throws "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: querySource" for navigation Properties

Tags: c#, automapper, ef-core-2.0

I am getting `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: querySource` error from Automapper when mapping navigation properties.

```
.ForMember(p => p.Region, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => 
  (p.RegAddressId.HasValue && p.RegAddress.CountryId.HasValue)? 
  p.RegAddress.Country.Region: p.Nationality.Region))
```

RegAddressId is nullable and NationalityId is not nullable.

```
public class User : IEntity
{
    ...
    public int NationalityId { get; set; }
    public int? RegAddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual LkupNationality Nationality { get; set; }
    public virtual Address RegAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Automapper Version is 7.0.1 and EF Core 2.0.3

Following is the expression which got from,

```
var expression = pendingRegs.ProjectTo<PendingClientModel>().Expression;

Region = .If (.If (
            ($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddressId).HasValue && (($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress).CountryId).HasValue && $dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress !=
            null && ($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress).Country != null
        ) {
            (($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress).Country).Region
        } .Else {
            ($dtoUserRegistration.Nationality).Region
        } == null) {
            null
        } .Else {
            .New Cft.Fbo.Domain.ViewModels.ListItemModel(){
                Desc = (.If (
                    ($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddressId).HasValue && (($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress).CountryId).HasValue && $dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress !=
                    null && ($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress).Country != null
                ) {
                    (($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress).Country).Region
                } .Else {
                    ($dtoUserRegistration.Nationality).Region
                }).Name,
                Id = (.If (
                    ($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddressId).HasValue && (($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress).CountryId).HasValue && $dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress !=
                    null && ($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress).Country != null
                ) {
                    (($dtoUserRegistration.RegAddress).Country).Region
                } .Else {
                    ($dtoUserRegistration.Nationality).Region
                }).Id
            }
        },
```

UPDATE: This is due to a bug in EF Core. I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14020#issuecomment-442191955) and will update the question once it is fixed. If anyone looking for a workaround, this is what I got from EF Core team.

> The work-around (in the absence of auto-mapper) would be not use null
>   check on navigation. EF Core does that for you already. Just make sure
>   to cast to nullable type in the end. In EFCore if you write
>   dtoUser.RegAddress.Country.Region.Id it will give you null if any
>   navigation is null else give you value of associated Id.

Comment: `p.RegAddress != null && p.Nationality != null`. Also Include those properties.

Comment: Hi Lucian, Tried. Same result.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: mapping working without any issue when remove the conditional part like this.  .ForMember(p => p.Region, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Nationality.Region))

Comment: Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sampathdr/70f47218aa9f32d8a86f5381f399db13  I created it without EF code. When run it, it works without any issue.

Comment: That looks like an EF Core issue to me. Using the execution plan you can write that query without AM.

Comment: Yes, it is an issue in EF Core. I have raised an issue in EF Core for that.  
    https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14020#issuecomment-442191955